# WPF application with local database

Tags: sql, wpf

I'm making a WPF application with a local database,

I made the database with SQL server management studio, then I linked a .edmx file to the database I made.

Now if i wanna run my program on another PC i don't have that database anymore so it kinda crashes.
Can I copy my database file (.mdf) in my Debug folder and change my App.Config so it takes that database?

Becouse I wanna copy my program to a computer that dosn't have SQL server Management studio installed. Is that posible?

My App.Config looks like this atm:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="PRCEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PRC.csdl|res://*/PRC.ssdl|res://*/PRC.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=DESKTOP-BERNARD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PRC;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the mdf but:

- The target machine has to have SQL Server installed
- You'll have [to attach the mdf file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx)
- You'll need to change the connection string, either let the user that installs the application enter it or change the machine name to localhost but you might run into machines that have named instances and no default instance.